# like finding errors overlap on the same layer in postgis?

Tags: postgis

After meeting the overlay erroneous   polygons in the same layer, I used the following query:

```
select gid from limite_localidad where not ST_Overlaps(the_geom,the_geom)
```

I have to leave `108` records error but brings me all records. 
if I make the same query in qgis with topology checker, it does well giving out 108 errors, but with `PostGIS` I don't know how to find these errors.

Comment: Use ST_IsValidDetail in PostGIS on geometry to locate topo errors http://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValidDetail.html

Comment: and used this function ST_IsValid Detail in PostGIS and I mark 0 errors, when if any

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'd need to join the layer with itself to find those errors. To avoid an expensive cross join, you could come up with something like this:

```
select gid from limite_localidad ll1
left join limite_localidad ll2
on ST_Intersects(ll1.the_geom, ll2.the_geom)
where ST_Overlaps(ll2.the_geom,ll1.the_geom)
```

I guess you'd have to decide how to narrow down the query results to get a quick response time, but the idea should point to the right direction.